# Reduce a list of object in Scala not working

Tags: scala

I am trying so reduce a list of object but Scala and my brain just doesn't converge (or I am thinking in a complete wrong way, haha). My question is quite simple, but I can't find the solution anyway.

The error is shown bellow:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : Double
 required: models.Transaction


def accountBalance(account: String): Double = {
    val accountTransactionList = Transaction.accountBalance(account)
    accountTransactionList.reduce {
        (transactionA, transactionB) => transactionA.amount + transactionB.amount 
    }
    0.0
}
```

Transaction.accountBalance(account) and my Object Transaction:

```
object Transaction {
    var accountTransactions = Map[String, List[Transaction]]()

    def accountBalance(account: String): List[Transaction] = accountTransactions.getOrElse(account, List[Transaction]())
}
```

I am returning 0.0 just so the code compiles, but why is scala expecting my class models.Transaction?

Thank you!!

Comment: reduce has input of an accumulator and the current value. I think you want to change `(transactionA, transactionB) => transactionA.amount + transactionB.amount ` to `(acc, transactionA) => acc + transactionA.amount`. Hard to say without more code.

Comment: @erip that doesn't work, it shows this error: Overloaded method value [+] cannot be applied to  (models.Transaction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the definition of `reduce()`.

```
def reduce[A1 >: A](op: (A1, A1) ⇒ A1): A1
```

Notice that all the types have to match. The collection has elements of type `A1` and the final result is type `A1`. It doesn't look like your attempt to reduce `accountTransactionList` meets this requirement.

`reduceLeft()` and `reduceRight()` are a little more flexible in this regard, but the `A` and `B` types still have to be related.

```
def reduceLeft[B >: A](op: (B, A) ⇒ B): B
```

Comment: Oh my god I am so dumb, I thought you could reduce a list into anything you wanted to, just like javascript. I think I got the idea! Thank you